# JPA Criteria in clause with tuple expression

Tags: jpa, tuples, criteria, criteria-api

Looking to translate an HQL query into it's JPA Criteria API equivalent.

In HQL I have the following which seems to work.

```
WHERE (x, y) IN (
    ... sub query which selects two columns
)
```

In JPA Criteria API I don't see how I can match a tuple value, only a single value. For example, I know how to convert the following to JPA Criteria.

```
WHERE (x) IN (
    ... sub query which selects single column
)
```

Is this even possible using the criteria api?

Comment: "(x,y) IN ..." is invalid JPQL, so no that won't be valid in Criteria either. Use native queries for such things

Comment: Hmm, OK. That's too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in JPQL to try to match two fields with the IN.

By the way, you can't do it in JPA Criteria neither.